# How to pass multiple OR and AND condition in Activate Record in Rails as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm new in Ruby on rails and I would like to fetch records based on a condition, and I'm passing the condition in a string format. Moreover, I will pass the query in multiple OR and AND conditions. However, right now, I'm stuck that how to pass the query in string format in rails
I have attached the screenshot  [image]

```
@data= CustomAttribute.includes(:custom_attribute_values).where(id: 18, company_id: current_user.company_id).first
```

The above line executed successfully and gave the output

```
<CustomAttribute id: 18, data_type: "string", label: "Marital status", code: "marital_status", entity_type: "member", company_id: 1, created_at: "2021-03-10 10:16:15", updated_at: "2021-03-10 10:16:27", is_active: true, is_default: false, rank: nil, is_identifier: false>
```

but when I executed the below line it gave me the error that

```
@data.custom_attribute_values.where("\""+"value_string"+"\""+"="+"\""+'Single'+"\"").size
```

**ERROR:  column "Single" does not exist**

the Single is the value which I would like to count

**Here is my code for the dynamic query creation**

```
logical_operator = 'OR'
  @custom_attribute = CustomAttribute.includes(:custom_attribute_values).where(id: custom_attribute_ids, company_id: current_user.company_id)

  query=""
  @custom_attribute.each_with_index do |attribute_object, index|

    filter_object= filter_params[:filters].find {|x| x['custom_attribute_id']==attribute_object['id']}

    if filter_object.present?
      query +=  "("+ '"' +'value_'+attribute_object.data_type + '"' + ' ' + filter_object['operator'] + ' ' + "'" +  filter_object['value'].to_s + "'"+ ")"
    end

    if index != @custom_attribute.length-1
      query+=' '+logical_operator+' '
    end

    if index == @custom_attribute.length-1
      query="'" + " ( " +  query + " ) " + "'"
    end

  end
  byebug
  
  puts(@custom_attribute.first.custom_attribute_values.where(query).size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're doing a lot of escaping and string addition in Ruby you're doing it wrong. If we clean up how you build your SQL:

```
"\""+"value_string"+"\""+"="+"\""+'Single'+"\""
```

things will be clearer. First, put space around your operators for readability:

```
"\"" + "value_string" + "\"" + "=" + "\"" + 'Single' + "\""
```

Next, don't use double quotes unless you need them for escape codes (such as `\n`) or interpolation:

```
'"' + 'value_string' + '"' + '=' + '"' + 'Single' + '"'
```

Now we see that we're adding several constant strings so there's no need to add them at all, a single string literal will do:

```
'"value_string" = "Single"'
```

Standard SQL uses double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names) and single quotes for strings. So your query is asking for all rows where the `value_string` column equals the `Single` column and there's your error.

You want to use single quotes for the string (and `%q(...)` to quote the whole thing to avoid adding escapes back in):

```
@data.custom_attribute_values.where(
  %q("value_string" = 'Single')
)
```

Or better, let ActiveRecord build the query:

```
# With a positional placeholder:
@data.custom_attribute_values.where('value_string = ?', 'Single')

# Or a named placeholder:
@data.custom_attribute_values.where('value_string = :s', s: 'Single')

# Or most idiomatic:
@data.custom_attribute_values.where(value_string: 'Single')
```